# Explanation of Typescript's intersection types

Tags: typescript, types

i was playing around with intersection types and i would expect following as working?

Could someone shed some light on it?

```
type SomeError = {    
    message: string;
    code?: number;    
};

type SomeResponse = {
    error: SomeError & { code: string; }
};

const response: SomeResponse = {
    error: {
        message: 'neco',
        code: 'a'
    } 
};

// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

const response2: SomeResponse = {
    error: {
        message: 'neco',
        code: 50
    } 
};

// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: You basically have `code: string & number`. How can you expect `code` to be both a `number` AND a `string`? Are you looking for [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) where you can define `code` to be `number` OR `string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it seems you want union types (with the `|`). Check out the [docs on advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and [use the online REPL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to test out theories.

Here's code that uses interfaces and union types to get a flexible number / string code in your error type.

```
interface SomeError {    
    message: string;
    code: number | string;    
};

interface SomeResponse {
    error: SomeError
}

const response: SomeResponse = {
    error: {
        message: 'neco',
        code: 'a'
    } 
};

const response2: SomeResponse = {
    error: {
        message: 'neco',
        code: 50
    } 
};
```

The docs lay out a use case for intersections, but it seems you just want specialization, which is where type guards come in, consider this function:

```
const printErrCode = (code: string | number) => {
    if(typeof code === "string") {
        console.error(code);
    } else {
        console.error(`Err code: ${code}`);
    }
}
```

Edit: if you want to play with intersection, try replicating the [extend function to create mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), but do it with your error domain. Try to make error serialization / loggable / printable etc. And then mixin a plain error object (with just a string or something) with an object that can log (like the example of ConsoleLogger).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `SomeResponse` has this type for `code`:

```
number & string
```

And that's impossible to have.

You can check that this is the case quite easily in [playground with your code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20SomeError%20%3D%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20message%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20code%3F%3A%20number%3B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20SomeResponse%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20error%3A%20SomeError%20%26%20%7B%20code%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20response%3A%20SomeResponse%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20error%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%3A%20'neco'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20code%3A%20'a'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20response.error.code%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20response2%3A%20SomeResponse%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20error%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%3A%20'neco'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20code%3A%2050%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%7D%3B):

```
let test = response.error.code;
```

The type of `test` is `number & string` (just hover over the variable name)